# Geometric median of multidimensional points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array of 3D points:

```
a = np.array([[2., 3., 8.], [10., 4., 3.], [58., 3., 4.], [34., 2., 43.]])
```

How can I compute the [geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) of those points?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617194/mode-median-mean-of-a-3d-numpy-array?

Comment: @EdChum Don't think so, I've looked at the implementation of `np.median`, and it seems to be implemented in terms of `partition` - that can't be right for geometric median.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I implemented Yehuda Vardi and Cun-Hui Zhang's algorithm for the geometric median, described in their paper ["The multivariate L1-median and associated data depth"](http://www.pnas.org/content/97/4/1423.full.pdf). Everything is vectorized in numpy, so should be very fast. I didn't implement weights - only unweighted points.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, euclidean

def geometric_median(X, eps=1e-5):
    y = np.mean(X, 0)

    while True:
        D = cdist(X, [y])
        nonzeros = (D != 0)[:, 0]

        Dinv = 1 / D[nonzeros]
        Dinvs = np.sum(Dinv)
        W = Dinv / Dinvs
        T = np.sum(W * X[nonzeros], 0)

        num_zeros = len(X) - np.sum(nonzeros)
        if num_zeros == 0:
            y1 = T
        elif num_zeros == len(X):
            return y
        else:
            R = (T - y) * Dinvs
            r = np.linalg.norm(R)
            rinv = 0 if r == 0 else num_zeros/r
            y1 = max(0, 1-rinv)*T + min(1, rinv)*y

        if euclidean(y, y1) < eps:
            return y1

        y = y1
```

In addition to the default SO license terms, I release the code above under the zlib license, if you so prefer.

Comment: I am currently looking for alternatives to using ArcGIS and this gets very close to the median center from using their Median Center Geoprocessing tool (+- 1m over 700+ pts). Any chance you could comment what is happening in the code? I'm not as suave with Python and Numpy yet. I have input a numpy array for X that contains the xy coords of the pts. I would like to know what is happening in the function if you have the tme to explain. Cheers

Comment: @Clubdebambos I'm not certain what you'd even want me to explain. You want to know why it differs by +- 1m? I don't have access to their code, so I have no clue what they're doing. And even if I did there's many reasons in both my and their code (numerical instability, floating point errors, multiple possible median candidates, a bug in the algorithm  or implementation), and I can't really be bothered to find out which it is.

Comment: I am not looking to compare, I want to implement your code in a workflow. At the moment I'd just be using it blindly, which I'm ok with, but I'd rather have some idea what is happening in the geometric_median function. I'm not at a level of coding that you are at so I can't follow it.

Comment: Oh like that. Sorry I don't think commenting line by line would be very useful, you can read the paper that I've linked.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a read and then get into learning the ins and outs of numpy and scipy. Fantastic function by the way. Perfect for my needs.

Comment: @Nabla It's been a while since I wrote the code, but I assume the same format as in the question.

Comment: I have the same question about the above code.  I'm trying to implement this geometric_median in my project.  I have a numpy array containing WorkerID, Latitude, and Longitude.  I want to get the median Latitude and Longitude per worker.  Should X be the tuple Latitude, Longitude?  And what would [y] be?

Comment: In some settings the convergence condition may not be met `||y - y1|| < eps`. Hence, I suggest replacing it with `||y - y1|| / ||y|| < eps`, which is more robust to oscillations or adding a maximum amount of iterations to avoid a rare (but possible) infinite loop.

Answer (score 9):

The calculation of the geometric median with the Weiszfeld's iterative algorithm  is implemented in Python in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/endolith/2837160) or in the function below copied from the [OpenAlea](http://openalea.gforge.inria.fr/dokuwiki/doku.php) software (CeCILL-C license),

```
import numpy as np
import math
import warnings

def geometric_median(X, numIter = 200):
    """
    Compute the geometric median of a point sample.
    The geometric median coordinates will be expressed in the Spatial Image reference system (not in real world metrics).
    We use the Weiszfeld's algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median)

    :Parameters:
     - `X` (list|np.array) - voxels coordinate (3xN matrix)
     - `numIter` (int) - limit the length of the search for global optimum

    :Return:
     - np.array((x,y,z)): geometric median of the coordinates;
    """
    # -- Initialising 'median' to the centroid
    y = np.mean(X,1)
    # -- If the init point is in the set of points, we shift it:
    while (y[0] in X[0]) and (y[1] in X[1]) and (y[2] in X[2]):
        y+=0.1

    convergence=False # boolean testing the convergence toward a global optimum
    dist=[] # list recording the distance evolution

    # -- Minimizing the sum of the squares of the distances between each points in 'X' and the median.
    i=0
    while ( (not convergence) and (i < numIter) ):
        num_x, num_y, num_z = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
        denum = 0.0
        m = X.shape[1]
        d = 0
        for j in range(0,m):
            div = math.sqrt( (X[0,j]-y[0])**2 + (X[1,j]-y[1])**2 + (X[2,j]-y[2])**2 )
            num_x += X[0,j] / div
            num_y += X[1,j] / div
            num_z += X[2,j] / div
            denum += 1./div
            d += div**2 # distance (to the median) to miminize
        dist.append(d) # update of the distance evolution

        if denum == 0.:
            warnings.warn( "Couldn't compute a geometric median, please check your data!" )
            return [0,0,0]

        y = [num_x/denum, num_y/denum, num_z/denum] # update to the new value of the median
        if i > 3:
            convergence=(abs(dist[i]-dist[i-2])<0.1) # we test the convergence over three steps for stability
            #~ print abs(dist[i]-dist[i-2]), convergence
        i += 1
    if i == numIter:
        raise ValueError( "The Weiszfeld's algoritm did not converged after"+str(numIter)+"iterations !!!!!!!!!" )
    # -- When convergence or iterations limit is reached we assume that we found the median.

    return np.array(y)
```

Alternatively, you could use the C implementation, mentionned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934484/1791279), and interface it to python with, for instance, `ctypes`.

Comment: This looks slow because it's pure Python - I'm looking for a fast numpy/scipy solution.

Comment: @orlp, a fast numpy/scipy solution requires that the code can be vectorized. From the first glance it is not obvious if that's possible at all. I guess the question here is: How fast do you have to get. I guess writing a `cython` version of the gist already gives you very good speed. Using a c-implementation as suggested in this answer could be even faster.

Comment: @rth It actually looks quite vectorizable to me, I'll give it a go.

Comment: @orlp Yes, you are right. Using `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`  for the distance calculation, should speed this up. Although, the `while` loop can't be avoided because of the iterative nature of the algorithm. BTW, if you manage to optimize the solution, feel free to contribute it back to the OpenAlea software.

Comment: @rth Exactly, I'm using `cdist` for my solution. I'm quite new to numpy/scipy however, so it will take me some time to cook it up :)

Comment: @orlp why should pure Python be slow? have you tried to use an [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) compiler such as [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)?

Comment: @Aprillion Python is incredibly slow compared to the vectorization you would get with numpy.

Comment: @cel See my answer for a vectorized numpy implementation.

Comment: it looks like this one returns the wrong answer for [[1, 1, 0], [1, -1, 0], [-1, -1, 0], [-1, 1, 0]]

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be easily approximated with `minimize` module in `scipy`. In this module, it provides various optimization algorithms, from nelder-mead to newton-CG. Nelder-mead algorithm is particular useful if you do not want to bother with high order derivatives, at a cost of losing some precision. Nevertheless, you just need to know the function to be minimized for [nelder-mead algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method)  to work.

Now, referring to the same array in the questions, if we use @orlp's method, we will get this:

```
geometric_median(a)
# array([12.58942481,  3.51573852,  7.28710661])
```

For Nelder-mead method, you will see below. The function to be minimized is the distance function from all points i.e.

[image: a formula]

Here is the code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
x = [point[0] for point in a]
y = [point[1] for point in a]
z = [point[2] for point in a]

x0 = np.array([sum(x)/len(x),sum(y)/len(y), sum(z)/len(z)])
def dist_func(x0):
    return sum(((np.full(len(x),x0[0])-x)**2+(np.full(len(x),x0[1])-y)**2+(np.full(len(x),x0[2])-z)**2)**(1/2))
res = minimize(dist_func, x0, method='nelder-mead', options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
res.x
# array([12.58942487,  3.51573846,  7.28710679])
```

Note that I use to mean of all points as the initial values for the alogrithm. The result is quite close to @orlp's method, which is more accurate. As I mentioned, you sacrifice a bit but still get quite good approximates.

**Performance of Nelder Mead Algorithm**
For this, I generated a `test_array` with 10000 entries of points from normal distribution centred at 3.2. Therefore, the geometric median should be quite close to [3.2, 3.2, 3.2].

```
np.random.seed(3)
test_array = np.array([[np.random.normal(3.2,20),
                        np.random.normal(3.2,20),
                        np.random.normal(3.2,20)] for i in np.arange(10000)])
```

For @orlp's method,

```
%timeit geometric_median(test_array)
# 12.1 ms ± 270 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# array([2.95151061, 3.14098477, 3.01468281])
```

For Nelder mead,

```
%timeit res.x
# 565 ms ± 14.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# array([2.95150898, 3.14098468, 3.01468276])
```

@orlp's method is very fast while Nelder mead is not bad. However, Nelder mead method is generic whereas @orlp's is specific to geometric median. The method you would like to choose would depend on your purpose. If you just want an approximate, I will choose Nelder at ease. If you want to be exact, @orlp's method is both faster and more accurate.