# How can I efficently pad an RGB numpy array with the median of the image?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have RGB images which have already been rescaled so that the longer edge becomes 256 pixels, now I want to pad the border with the median RGB values of that image so the resulting image is always 256x256 pixels.

This code already works, but I am sure there could be a simpler more elegant way to do this:

```
img = loadAndFitImage(filePath, maxSideLength=256, upscale=True)
shp = img.shape
#the shp in this case is typically (256,123,3) or (99,256,3)

leftPad = (256 - shp[0]) / 2
rightPad = 256 - shp[0] - leftPad
topPad = (256 - shp[1]) / 2
bottomPad = 256 - shp[1] - topPad

# this part looks like there might be a way to do it with one median call instead of 3:
median = (np.median(img[:, :, 0]),np.median(img[:, :, 1]),np.median(img[:, :, 2]))

img = np.lib.pad(img, ((leftPad,rightPad),(topPad,bottomPad),(0,0)),
 'constant',constant_values=0)

if leftPad > 0:
    img[:leftPad,:,0].fill(median[0])
    img[:leftPad,:,1].fill(median[1])
    img[:leftPad,:,2].fill(median[2])
if rightPad > 0:
    img[-rightPad:,:,0].fill(median[0])
    img[-rightPad:,:,1].fill(median[1])
    img[-rightPad:,:,2].fill(median[2])
if topPad > 0:
    img[:,:topPad,0].fill(median[0])
    img[:,:topPad,1].fill(median[1])
    img[:,:topPad,2].fill(median[2])
if bottomPad > 0:
    img[:,-bottomPad:,0].fill(median[0])
    img[:,-bottomPad:,1].fill(median[1])
    img[:,-bottomPad:,2].fill(median[2])
```

Edit (Additional Info):

- This is how the final result should look like:
- [image: Desired:]
- This is how it should not look like (median per column):
- [image: Undesired:]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it easily with:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
     [8,4,5,6,7,7],
     [1,2,3,4,5,6],
     [1,2,3,4,5,6],
     [1,2,3,4,5,6],
     [1,2,3,4,5,6]])

b = a * 3
c = a * 4
d = (a,b,c)

im = np.asarray([np.pad(x, (2,), 'constant', constant_values=(np.median(x) ,)) for x in d])
print im
```

Output:

```
[[[ 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4]
  [ 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4]
  [ 4  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  4  4]
  [ 4  4  8  4  5  6  7  7  4  4]
  [ 4  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  4  4]
  [ 4  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  4  4]
  [ 4  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  4  4]
  [ 4  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  4  4]
  [ 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4]
  [ 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4]]

 [[12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12]
  [12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12]
  [12 12  3  6  9 12 15 18 12 12]
  [12 12 24 12 15 18 21 21 12 12]
  [12 12  3  6  9 12 15 18 12 12]
  [12 12  3  6  9 12 15 18 12 12]
  [12 12  3  6  9 12 15 18 12 12]
  [12 12  3  6  9 12 15 18 12 12]
  [12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12]
  [12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12]]

 [[16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16]
  [16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16]
  [16 16  4  8 12 16 20 24 16 16]
  [16 16 32 16 20 24 28 28 16 16]
  [16 16  4  8 12 16 20 24 16 16]
  [16 16  4  8 12 16 20 24 16 16]
  [16 16  4  8 12 16 20 24 16 16]
  [16 16  4  8 12 16 20 24 16 16]
  [16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16]
  [16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16]]]
```

Or in you particular case:

[image: Original Image]

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

filePath = '/home/george/Desktop/img.jpg'

Img = Image.open(filePath)
img = np.asarray(Img, np.int)
shp = np.shape(img)
img = img.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(3,215,215)

leftPad = round(float((255 - shp[0])) / 2)
rightPad = round(float(255 - shp[0]) - leftPad)
topPad = round(float((255 - shp[1])) / 2)
bottomPad = round(float(255 - shp[1]) - topPad)
pads = ((leftPad,rightPad),(topPad,bottomPad))

img_arr = np.ndarray((3,255,255),np.int)
for i,x in enumerate(img):
    cons = np.int(np.median(x))
    x_p = np.pad(x,pads,
                'constant', 
                 constant_values=cons)
    img_arr[i,:,:] = x_p

im_shp = np.shape(img_arr)
ii = np.uint8(img_arr).transpose(1,2,0)

im = Image.fromarray(np.array( (ii) ))
im.show()
im.save((filePath), "JPEG")
```

**Output:**

[image: Median Padded Image]

Comment: Thank you! But looking at your example it seems like the median gets calculated per-row or per-column. What I am looking for is that the entire padded area gets filled with the median of the entire image. Also my particular difficulty is understanding the correct syntax to do this for all the 3 channels in on step.

Comment: Thanks for the update! The problem is that this works for a 1 channel greyscale image, but I am particularly looking for a solution that handles 3 channel RGB arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not work. The shape of the array in your upper example is (3,6,6) whereas in the image format used it would be (6,6,3) - I've tried shifting things around to make it work but my Python knowledge is still rudimentary in that part, so I failed so far.

Comment: @Quasimondo It was a tough work around but simply I can't leave you yourself with this problem. :)

Comment: My pleasure buddy!  Anyway, some Kaggle work or other? :)

Comment: "other" - but it's ML related, yes :-)

Answer (score 6):

I was also struggling on this and figured out an elegant answer:

`color = np.median(img, axis=(0,1))
img = np.stack([np.pad(img[:,:,c], pad, mode='constant', constant_values=color[c]) for c in range(3)], axis=2)`

Comment: What is the argument `pad`?

Comment: if 2 rows and 2 columns you want to pad, then (2,)

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the median can be done with `median = np.median(img.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0)` or something similar, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21617503/2647279).

The padding can probably be done with a single line per side, something like `img[:leftPad,:,:] = median`. Have a look at the [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: It doesn't work as expected because you are filling pixels of the image, not adding new pixels as pad: in you case img.shape == padded(img).shape; however, you should add new pixels, so, padded image must be larger than original one

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but here goes another suggestion:

```py
def pad_image(img, color, border_width=.1):
    """
    pads image img with given color. 
    Color must be in same color space as image (usually, RGB). 
    border_width is expected to be the fraction of padding you want to add,
    with respect to the shorter dimension of the image.
    """
    h, w, c = img.shape

    # compute the number of pixels you'll pad
    border = int(float(min(h, w) * border_width))  

    # compute the "new background"
    result = np.full((h+2*border, w+2*border, c), color, dtype=img.dtype)
    
    # now fill this "new background" with your original image in the center
    result[border:-border, border:-border] = img

    return result
```

Usage example:

```py
img = np.zeros((11,21, 3), dtype=np.uint8)  # create simple black image

img = pad_image(img, (128,0,0), .25)

plt.imshow(img)
```

Which outputs this:

[image: output image: a black image surrounded by dark-red border]

For this particular case, as other said, you need to compute the median color before padding:

```py
color = np.median(img, axis=(0,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this can be done more simply using a single `np.pad()` call:

```py
  value = np.median(image, axis=(0, 1))
  pad = 2
  cval = np.array([[value, value], [value, value], [0, 0]], dtype=object)  # Ragged.
  image2 = np.pad(image, ((pad, pad), (pad, pad), (0, 0)), constant_values=cval)
```